# How to newline in vscode.window.showInformationMessage

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to use `vscode.window.showInformationMessage` to show some message. But I cannot newline in it.

**What I want:**

```
title:xxx
description:xxx
```

**I actual get:**

```
title:xxx description:xxx
```

**My code:**

```
vscode.window.showInformationMessage("title:xxx\ndescription:xxx");
```

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/48900#issuecomment-385332787

Comment: One and a half year later, and this still seems to be impossible to achieve, although it seem to me like one of the most fundamental features... Their own native editor notifications are able to show multi lines, so why aren't we able to? Please tag me if any news on this. I need this feature a lot

Comment: I opened this as a feature request on VSCode again. They are taking upvotes to add it to their backlog. So if you want it, please vote here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/101589#issuecomment-653355456

Answer (score 11):

As the OP already noted in a comment, the request for this capability is filed as [Issue #48900](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/48900), which has been closed as "will not do".  VSCode explicitly [strips newline characters](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/8616dbae8bc2abf7972a45449b0fb6b2b2d0f429/src/vs/workbench/common/notifications.ts#L412-L413) from the message text, and the VSCode team wants to keep it that way.

On 2020-07-20, a new issue, [#101589](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/101589), was filed asking again for this feature, but that too was eventually rejected as "out of scope" after some discussion.

I am simply summarizing this already-present information in an answer so it is clear the question has been answered.

Answer (score 7):

This is not exactly the solution but you can use modal dialog option.

```
vscode.window.showInformationMessage('First line\nSecond line\nThird line', { modal: true });
```

[image]

With the custom dialog enabled in `settings.json` it looks like:

```js
"window.dialogStyle": "custom",// VSCode >= 1.50.0
```

[image]

Comment: You can also use string literals in a modal message and their whitespace will be respected.